# angularjs variable undefined, null, and empty all at the same time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
Partial Cart: {{PARTIAL_CART}}

<div ng-if"PARTIAL_CART === null">
Null
</div>

<div ng-if"PARTIAL_CART === undefined">
undefined</div>

<div ng-if"PARTIAL_CART === ''">
empty
</div>
```

When I view this in a browser, I get the following:

Partial Cart:
Null
undefined
empty

How is PARTIAL_CART undefined, null, and the empty string all at the same time?  I thought about type coercion, but my understanding was that === disables type coercion.  What is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Missing `=` after `ng-if`

```
<div ng-if = "PARTIAL_CART === null">
<!--       ^                      -->
```

Without `=` it'll be considered as single custom HTML attribute `ng-ifPARTIAL_CART` and will not be parsed.